# Placing children div tags in horizontal, despite parent div tag width

Tags: html, css

Given this css:

```
#parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #090;
}
.childs {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: #009;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

and this html:

```
   <div id="parent">
        <div class="childs"><p>aaa</p></div>
        <div class="childs"></div>
        <div class="childs"></div>
   </div>
```

this is demo
http://jsfiddle.net/A3PJu/2/

I want that children divs placing in horizontal and not in vertical (as are they now), how make this?

`float: left` for children tags, not working in  this case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **display:inline-block** with **white-space:nowrap**. Write like this:

```
#parent {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #090;
        white-space:nowrap;
        font-size:0;
    }
    .childs {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #008;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        display:inline-block;
        *display:inline;/* For IE7 */
        *zoom:1;/* For IE7 */
        white-space:normal;
        font-size:13px;
        vertical-align:top;
    }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/A3PJu/3/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the width of the parent element is not big enough for 3 times 50px `.childs`. If you increase the `#parent` width to say 200px, `float: left` will work.

Comment: But I need that `#parent` div tag width, will be exactly 100px

Comment: Sorry, did not see this info in the title. The solution from @sandeep should work fine then.